# Parse a JSON file with Javascript (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I try desperately to parse a JSON file with Javascript.

Here my datas :

```
{
    "streetCity":
    {
        "132":"Abergement-Clemenciat",
        "133":"Abergement-de-Varey",
        "134":"Amareins"
    }
}
```

I want just access to each data but I've tried but I failed.

Have you got an idea to read this data ?

Thank you !

Best regards

Comment: @mkoryak A file with the extension `.json`, that contains JSON data.

Comment: JSON is javascript, you shouldn't need to parse it.

Comment: @Scipius2012 [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: browser-based JS has no concept of files. It has no native file operations.

Comment: JSON is not JavaScript. Though if you're using jQuery, you shouldn't need to parse it.

Comment: 1.) You don't parse JSON 2.)That's an improper JSON object

Comment: @Scipius2012 what are you trying to do with a JSON file? Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: @jrummell: JSON **is not** JavaScript.

Comment: You have to provide some more information. For example, how are you getting the data from the JSON file? How are you trying to process the data? Provide your code!

Comment: @FelixKling, Greg Pettit - thanks for pointing that out. Care to explain?

Comment: @jrummell: JSON is data exchange format, like XML. JSON can be *parsed as JavaScript* without problems, since the syntax of JSON is similar to JavaScript object and array literals (and other literals), but that alone does not make it JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to parse a file you can use `.getJSON()` function from `jQuery` library. Then you can easily create a script that reads the data and then do something with it.

```
 $.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
      alert (data.value1)
 });
```

For more information read the links [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) and [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

Comment: his json file is not valid json. this wont work

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {
    "streetCity":
    {
        "132":"Abergement-Clemenciat",
        "133":"Abergement-de-Varey",
        "134":"Amareins"
    }
};

obj.streetCity[132]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume, by saying JSON file, you meant you have some `JSON` in your script.

```
var data={
    "streetCity":
    {
        "132":"Abergement-Clemenciat",
        "133":"Abergement-de-Varey",
        "134":"Amareins"
    }
}; 
$.each(data.streetCity,function(index,item){

       alert(item);            
});
```

Sample http://jsfiddle.net/yjXjh/4/

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

JSON with quotes and single quotes must be parsed.

If you create your JSON with no quotes and single quotes (which is improper format) then you can just set the JSON equal to a variable. But don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your data, or your data is in this form, then you can simply use.

```
var obj = {"streetCity":
    {
        "132":"Abergement-Clemenciat",
        "133":"Abergement-de-Varey",
        "134":"Amareins"
    }
    };
console.log(typeof(obj)); // will tell the type, it should be object
obj.streetCity['132']  will return Abergement-Clemenciat",
```

It will behave like a JSON object.

Else, if your data is dynamically generated, use **[jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)** function to get the JSON data from server. It'll return data in JSON format.